# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sentry')

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sentry

Using unit tests in nodejs with jest and sentry-testkit.
Running the test I get the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sentry')

```
import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';
import sentryTestKit from 'sentry-testkit';

const { testkit, sentryTransport } = sentryTestKit();

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'my-dsa',
  transport: sentryTransport,
});

describe('Sentry Test', () => {
  describe('Error Capture', () => {
    it('should be able to catch the error', () => {
      expect(testkit.reports()).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the full error stack?

Comment: I achieved. sentry-testkit is for browser

Comment: Add the full error. The more details, the better. Here you have a link to learn how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask